# "Document contains trailing content not separated by a ... or --- line" syntax error when running prettier on yaml

Tags: yaml, prettier

I have this code in a YAML file.

```
# prettier-ignore
{% set data = load_setup_py_data(setup_file='./setup.py', from_recipe_dir=True) %}

package:
    name: covalent
    version: {{ data.get('version') }}
```

When I run Prettier on the file, I get `SyntaxError: Document contains trailing content not separated by a ... or --- line`, pointing to the `package:` line. I can't seem to find any information on this rule in Prettier docs or elsewhere. Anyone know how to resolve it, or what rule is being enforced?

Answer (score 1):

Prettier assumes this is a YAML file, but it isn't. You are using some templating engine that processes the `{% … %}` and `{{ … }}` parts.

While the `{{ … }}` part can technically be read as YAML, the `{% … %}` part can't. Generally, you can't pretty-print a file that will only be YAML after preprocessing by a templating engine. This only works in specific cases where the content happens to be valid YAML even without preprocessing. This is not the case here.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to `# prettier-ignore` the templated line? Even with `# prettier-ignore` immediately before that line the error is the same.

Comment: @ScottWymanNeagle That depends on the implementation. Since I don't know prettier internals, I don't know the details, but from what we're seeing I assume that prettier always parses the whole YAML file *but* only reformats the lines that are not ignored. In YAML, you cannot take away a line and assume the rest still parses, therefore it would make sense that it works like this.